# Form being submitted without passing jQuery Validation plugin test

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, local-storage

I have a form that is submitting fields to localstorage. The validators are working, but the form is still submitting the fields that have passed, even when failed validations have not. How can I keep the form from submitting until all fields have passed their validations?

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/xh4ho0hc/)

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Add Publisher</div>
            <!-- /.panel-heading -->
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label class="control-label" for="name">Publisher Name:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control name" placeholder="Publisher Name" name="name" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label class="control-label" for="website">Website:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control website" placeholder="website" name="website" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                            <label class="control-label" for="contact">Contact:</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control contact" placeholder="Point of Contact" name="contact" type="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel-body -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /#page-wrapper -->
```

jQuery:

```
 $('form').validate({
 rules: {
     name: {
         minlength: 3,
         maxlength: 35,
         required: true
     },
     phone: {
         minlength: 9,
         maxlength: 10,
         required: true
     },
     website: {
         required: true,
         url: true
     },
     contact: {
         required: true,
         minlength: 2
     }
 },
 highlight: function (element) {
     $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
 },
 unhighlight: function (element) {
     $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
 },
 errorElement: 'span',
 errorClass: 'help-block',
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
     if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
         error.insertAfter(element.parent());
     } else {
         error.insertAfter(element);
     }
 }


});
 $("#submit").click(function () {
     var name = $(".name").val();
     var phone = $(".phone").val();
     var website = $(".website").val();
     var contact = $(".contact").val();
     localStorage.setItem('name', name);
     localStorage.setItem('phone', phone);
     localStorage.setItem('website', website);
     localStorage.setItem('contact', contact);
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom `click` handler is over-riding the click event of the validation plugin.  Get rid if the `click` handler and copy its code into [the `submitHandler` callback option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler) of the plugin.  This function will only fire when the button is clicked AND validation is satisfied.

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 35,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 10,
            required: true
        },
        website: {
            required: true,
            url: true
        },
        contact: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.parent('.input-group').length) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        var name = $(".name").val();
        var phone = $(".phone").val();
        var website = $(".website").val();
        var contact = $(".contact").val();
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
        localStorage.setItem('phone', phone);
        localStorage.setItem('website', website);
        localStorage.setItem('contact', contact);
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Updated DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/xh4ho0hc/2/**

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm seeing is with your function at the bottom. When that function fires, you're setting localStorage's variables regardless of the validator, and independent of it.

Consider using a variable and some logic to see if all variables pass validation. Loop through your form-control elements and only set the variables if all of them actually pass validation. Easiest thing to do is check to see if those elements have the ".has-error" class